# Is it possible to keep 2 similar git repos with different file names in sync?

Tags: git, repository

We have 2 git repos, one of which we expose to a third party library where we want to share our changesets as part of the git history, but their filenames are slightly different.

Currently we have a shell script that will copy over all of the files and handle the renaming, however, this is not ideal because when we go to commit in the other repository, it goes in as one large commit (so it's missing the changes, as well as the reasons for those changes).

An example of the type of stuff we do would be:
Let's say in repo A (our source that we work in day to day) we have a structure like:

```
module-x/
    module-x.js
```

In repo B (where we want to copy our commits into), the structure looks like this:

```
gallery-module-x/
    gallery-module-x.js
```

(in addition, there are other scriptable changes in the content of the files as well).

Is there a way to either copy of the history and run the script on the files to sync them up (but keeping the content changes and commit message, so creating a new commit in the third party repo)?

I was thinking of setting up either a post-commit hook locally, or a post-receive hook on github, but wasn't sure if it's possible to do that, or if there's a better way to do this.

Any advice? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you try to add original repo as remote and pull? At least **you can try it** on fresh clone: clone, rename files, pull - if Git with it's heuristic will not handle task properly, I'll write it as one more example for "Git is moron" list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you do is going to be pretty ugly, since Git at a fundamental level knows what the filenames are supposed to be. A tree with different filenames has a different SHA1, so the commits do too, and nothing will ever match up. This means that there's not really anything reasonable you can do on GitHub, since there's a lot of history rewriting that has to take place.

There are two primary things you could try doing.

**One:** use `git filter-branch` with a tree or index filter to rewrite all of history in one repo, renaming the files. You can read the documentation or search online or here to find examples of that. There's an example in the manpage that's fairly close to your use case, the last one in the example section, which moves all files into a subdirectory, doing so in a way that's basically equivalent to removing or adding a prefix. Your version might be something like:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
               'git ls-files -s | sed "s/module-x/gallery-module-x/" |
                       GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
                               git update-index --index-info &&
                mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
```

(The sed replacement pattern is where you need to be careful.) You'd want to run it in a fresh clone, to avoid actually rewriting the branches in your original repo.

If you're working in both repositories, this will require a lot of careful work to stay in sync, avoiding mismatches between the two repos, and you'd have to do the opposite transformation to bring things back the other way. But if the exposed/shared one is read-only, then this option is wonderful; think of the filter-branch as a precursor to exporting. Save a script to do this, and all you'll have to do is clone, filter-branch, and push.

**Two:** manually transfer patches. You can use `git format-patch <revision-range>` to create patches, then do some automatic replacement of filenames in those patches, then apply them in the other repository. It's ugly, but it does work.

I suppose that you *could* trigger either of these things off of a post-commit hook locally, but they might be more time-consuming than you want, since you'll probably commit often and want to move on immediately. One other option, which I assume you've already considered and dismissed for some reason, is to use your existing script, kicked off from a post-commit hook, to copy/rename files into the other repo, and immediately commit there. (One commit per commit, not one large commit per several commits.)

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'm not sure which one I'll go with, as they both sound like workable options, but I'll play around with a copy of the repo and test them out. Also, thanks a ton for formatting the sed command to match my example. My sed-fu is weak, and the git filter-branch man page example was a bit odd, but this gets me on the right path. Again, thanks a ton :)

Comment: And as for why I'm not running the current script post-commit, basically the script makes a copy of the repo and does a ton of work on ALL of the files, (it's about a 45-60s or so long on an SSD), and doing all that after every commit, as you mentioned, would make every day dev a nightmare. But I was hoping that if I do a smaller batch of changes for every commit, it would be smaller. But doing it all at one time may be where format-patch comes in handy.

Comment: @NateCavanaugh: Since that's just a pipeline, drop in whatever you're comfortable with instead of `sed`; it just has to transform filenames and leave the rest of the line unchanged.

Comment: quick question as an aside (not sure if this was worth an entirely separate question), but what if I wanted to edit the content of each commit as well (so that references to module/ would instead point to gallery-module/)? I've tried everything from using the index-filter, the tree-filter, the commit filter as well as just trying to update the index as I'm looping through during the index-filter, but I can't seem to see if modifying the content of the history is possible. Do you happen to know? Thanks!

Comment: @NateCavanaugh: For that you'd have to use a tree-filter. It'll be slow; index-filter is fast because it doesn't actually have to check out the files. With a tree-filter you can do both the renaming and the substitutions in the tree, with normal commands (including perhaps bits of the script that you'd previously written).

Answer (score 0):

If only the git repository (directory) has a different name, you could make it easier on yourself by setting another git remote: `git remote add <their-remote> <git-remote-url>`. I would hope this is the case for you as it's a far easier method.

However, if filenames differ as well, but the code within those files are the same, you could create a `git patch`, and run a `sed` or other find-replace command to change the filenames within that single patch file, and then `git apply` the patch to the other repository. This could indeed be done using a post commit hook and scripted.

Comment: It's partially filenames, but also *some* code has to change (basically fixed parts that will probably never be part of the changeset). Thanks for the response :)